# Setting NSObject to nil hangs my app

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I am trying to transition from one view controller to another when a user presses a cancel button. Before I call dismissViewController, I am setting another object to nil.

This object is a manager controlling a multipeer connection and state associated with it. When I set it to nil: `_appDelegate.manager = nil;` the app hangs for about 5 seconds, and then works again. I've used the profiler and nothing is really happening in cpu or memory. I'm really confused. Is it possible that it has something to do with the fact that multipeer is using other threads?

This is the header file for ConnectionManager if that is helpful.

```
@interface ConnectionManager : NSObject <MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) MCPeerID *peerID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCNearbyServiceBrowser *browser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser *advertiser; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCSession *session;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *sessions;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL leader;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *currentRequestingPeers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *allMessages;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *leadersPublicKey;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *nameOfProtest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *foundProtests;

- (void)joinProtest:(NSString*)protestName password:(NSString*)password;
- (void)startProtest:(NSString*)name password:(NSString*)password;
- (void)pruneTree;
- (void)sendMessage:(NSString*)message;
- (void)searchForProtests;
- (void)reset;
- (void)testMessageSending;

@end
```

Comment: If you put an `NSLog` before and after that line, is the app actually sitting on that line for five seconds?  If so, it may be helpful to add more information/code about `manager` to your question, including but not limited to, the class of `manager`.

Comment: There's a vague possibility that this is some sort of ARC artifact -- either destroying the manager object or going around checking all the weak references on it.

Comment: @HotLicks good idea... if you have more than a certain amount of weak references to an object, the weak-ref implementation becomes rather inefficient (slow). that would be a plausible theory...

Comment: @user3386109 Did as you said. The app is actually sitting on that line for 5 seconds. I'll add the header file for ConnectionManager to the question. What other information would be helpful?

@ Michael, How would I go about testing for this?

Comment: Are you disconnecting and cleaning up before niling out the Multipeer stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't disconnecting from my multipeer connections. You must call `[session disconnect]` before you destroy the session.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general debugging tip (posted as an answer because it doesn't work as a comment).

My guess is that some portion of the shutdown procedure is waiting for a response from the network, and lacking that response, times out after 5 seconds. If you're lucky, some portion of your code is involved, something that you will recognize as waiting for a network event.

To find out, run the app with the debugger. When the app hangs, press the pause button.  Then open the Debug navigator, and examine the state of each thread. Specifically, click on each line of user code (with the blue icon) and see what your code is doing in each thread.

[image]